# ActionController::UnknownFormat with rspec and post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to do some integration tests with rspec on rails 4 but I alway get a "ActionController::UnknownFormat" exception when running the tests.

I tried two different ways:

```
Failure/Error: post sensors_path, sensor: @sensor_attributes.to_json
ActionController::UnknownFormat:
    ActionController::UnknownFormat


Failure/Error: post sensors_path, sensor: @sensor_attributes, format: :js
ActionController::UnknownFormat:
    ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Here is the rspec code:

```
it "should change the number of sensors" do
    lambda do
        post sensors_path, sensor: @sensor_attributes.to_json 
        end.should change(Sensor, :count).by(1)
    end

it "should be successful" do
    post sensors_path, sensor: @sensor_attributes, format: :js
    response.should be_success
end
```

And this is the create statement of the controller:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json do
            @sensor = Sensor.new(params["sensor"])
            @sensor.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid

            @sensor.save

            render nothing: true
        end
    end
end
```

And the sensor_attributes:

```
before do
    @sensor_attributes = { name: "Testname", description: "This is a Test-Description." }
end
```

And the routes:

```
resources :sensors
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: are you trying to test the create method?

Comment: Oh, I'm sory. But You've drawn the right conclusions. I wanna test the create method.

Comment: these aren't integration specs.... they're simple controller specs and as such should be tested in the context of a controller with `post :create`.

Comment: Finaly I get it running by upgrading rspec-rails to 3.0.0beta2. Maybe it's a problem between rspec-rails 2.x and rails 4.0.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're using `json` format in controller, but you're passing `format: :js` in the test.

It should be:

`post sensors_path, sensor: @sensor_attributes, format: :json`

Comment: This did'nt help either. But after switching ti rspec-rails 3.0.0.beta2 (see comment above) format: :json is nescessary.

Comment: This is no longer the right way, check @Disha's answer instead

Answer (score 6):

This is for future readers. 
Somehow the answer did not help me.

Writing like following worked for me -

```
params = {
    sensor: { 
       name: "Testname", 
       description: "This is a Test-Description." 
    },
    format: :json
  }

  post sensors_path, params
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending `.json` to the path worked for me as well (since I was using a shared rspec example and could not just append `format: json`)...

post "#{sensors_path}.json", sensor: @sensor_attributes

Answer (score -2):

```
it "creates a new sensor" do
    expect {
       post :create, {:sensor => {here_you_need_to_put_the_variables_which_are_needed_to_create_a_sensor}}
    }.to change(Sensor, :count).by(1)
end
```

In you **create** method, the following line

```
@sensor = Sensor.new(params["sensor"])
```

should be:

```
@sensor = Sensor.new(params[:sensor])
```

I don't know the structure of you code. All the solution code i gave is based on my own assumption.

Comment: if you give the code of the controller and model, then it would be more helpful for me to answer.

Comment: The params hash is a HashWithIndifferentAccess - indexing by strings or symbols is identical.